# font weight in emacs doesn’t work

Tags: emacs, fonts

There’s a font named Meslo. It’s a patched version of a Menlo typeface by Apple, which, in its turn, is a derivative work from Bitstream Vera Mono. I was picking it to try several times, but either the font itself was bad or emacs rendered it poorly. [The patched version](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Meslo) though seems to be okay, but it feels too heavy in comparison with DejaVu Sans Mono (literally Bitstream Vera font extended with more glyphs). In the `customize-face` menu `weight` option doesn’t produce any change to the look. Is it supposed to work only when typeface has specific fonts that are lighter?

Example of DejaVu Sans Mono (above) and Meslo (below)
[image: dejavu and maslo.png]
Note the strange thickness of the latter: two dashes (`--msgbox`) alomst blend, letters have stems of unequal width which makes it look worse than DejaVu, though Meslo forms of the glyphs are more appealing to me.
Or, maybe it’s supposed to be used only on 72 dpi Apple displays :D

// S, M and L versions of Meslo seem to differ by the leading and aren’t treated as variant of one font.

Answer (score 1):

If a font doesn't have different weights they will not be synthesized, so the weight option in emacs (as in any other app) will not work.
About Meslo font: I think this patched version lacks rendering hints, which are present in the original Meslo (but it looks like they are not optimized for freetype rendering)

Comment: Are `fonts.*` files in that repo somehow related to rendering hints? I just don’t know what to do with them.

Comment: @tijagi, no, they are just index files for X. Here's a [doc page](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.0/doc/fonts2.html) about them. Font hints are built into the font.